# Merge each row with corresponding column to form a vertical table

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge each row in `b` to each column in `a` so that I can create a vertical table of all the data.

Suppose I have the following:

```
a <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3,4), col2=c(5,6,7,8), col3=c(9,10,11,12))
b <- data.frame(p=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

I would like to merge the corresponding columns in `a` for each row of `b`. 
NOTE: Would prefer a base R solution but other solutions would be interesting to learn.

Trying to get my final result to look like the following:

```
p | val
-------
a | 1
a | 2
a | 3
a | 4
b | 5
b | 6
b | 7
b | 8
c | 9
c | 10
c | 11
c | 12
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to earlier `stack(setNames(a, b$p))`

Comment: holy batman, how'd you think of it that fast? You saved me about an hour's worth of experimentation. Need to learn about this stack command.

Comment: @akrun feel free to put that as the answer

Comment: @akrun - I'll upvote your answer. Would be nice to have an answer as a lot of people have looked at this now. I like to keep these questions around because I run over these same problems over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by setting the column names of the 'a' dataset with the 'p' column of 'b' and then `stack` the data.frame into a two column `data.frame` with one column representing the column names and the second with the values of the column

```
stack(setNames(a, b$p))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>%
   rename_all(~ b$p) %>%
   gather %>% 
   rename(!! rlang::sym(names(b)) := key, val = value)
```